# OCaml build failure in Homebrew on Snow Leopard

Tags: installation, ocaml, homebrew, freetype

I'm having trouble installing `objective-caml` on Snow Leopard with Homebrew.  (Actually, I had previously installed OCaml a few months ago, but a recent update always fails which is making it impossible to compile.)  The build always fails with this error:

```
Reason: Incompatible library version: libtk8.6.dylib requires version 14.0.0 or later, libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
make[3]: *** [labltktop] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [otherlibraries] Error 2
make: *** [world] Error 2
```

So apparently I need a more recent version of Freetype.  Installing `freetype` with Homebrew does not change anything.  Is there an extra command line argument I need to build against the Freetype that Homebrew installed?  I tried both `--with-freetype` and `--without-freetype`.

Comment: It's not that you need a newer version of freetype, but a newer version of TK. If you can add custom arguments, adding `-no-graph` should remove the libtk dependency for compilation --if you don't plan on using the graphics module.

Comment: Can I simply use Homebrew to get a newer version of TK?